# Is it possible to create materialized view based on another materialized view in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, materialized-view

I have a very large table and I summarize it in a materialized view. I then create an even smaller materialized view based on the earlier mview. The second mv is always showing zero rows. Is there a limitation in postgres that all mvs must be based off of a real table? I did a quick search of docs and didn't find anything.

table (millions of rows) -> mv A (thousands of rows) -> mv B (zero rows, but expected hundreds)

Comment: No, there is no such limitation. But you need to refresh them in the correct order.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name looks like you are right. My refresh statements were out of order